# Outlook 2007 to prompt to save or delete sent item when SEND is clicked

Tags: microsoft-outlook, prompt

In outlook 2007, I would like to be prompted to Save or Delete the message after I click on Send button. 
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a VBA macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa209971%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and attach it to the "Application.[ItemSend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa171284%28v=office.11%29.aspx)" event.

Here's some macro code you can put in there that will ask you if you want to save it to the "Sent" folder, or just delete it:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

  Dim mailItem As Outlook.mailItem
  Dim strPrompt As String
  Dim response As VbMsgBoxResult

  strPrompt = "Do you want to save this email in the Sent folder?"
  response = MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo, "Save to Sent folder?")

  If (response = vbNo) Then
    Set mailItem = Item
    mailItem.DeleteAfterSubmit = True
  End If

End Sub
```